# Google Analytics Embed API Service Account Access Token

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-api-python-client, service-accounts, oauth2client

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/

I have created a Google service account in anticipation of using the Google Analytics Embed API and have been provided a *.json* key file.  I am now attempting to execute the above Google instructions to install Google's [Python API Client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation).  The *google-api-python-client* Python module is being installed properly, however when I attempt to execute the provided Python code to obtain the access token I get the following message:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
ImportError: No module named oauth2client.service_account
```

I have wasted hours trying to resolve this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Mac OS High Sierra.

Comment: Well... what Python packages have you loaded? Which versions are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got briefly stuck on this recently too. While their documentation tells you to install the `google-api-python-client` via pip just fine, you still need to install the `oauth2client` too if you haven't already (which it seems you haven't).

You can do that like this:

`pip install --upgrade oauth2client`

Then try again and it should work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what got installed...

Installing collected packages: httplib2, pyasn1, rsa, cachetools, six, pyasn1-modules, google-auth, google-auth-httplib2, uritemplate, google-api-python-client
Successfully installed cachetools-2.1.0 google-api-python-client-1.7.4 google-auth-1.5.0 google-auth-httplib2-0.0.3 httplib2-0.11.3 pyasn1-0.4.4 pyasn1-modules-0.2.2 rsa-3.4.2 six-1.11.0 uritemplate-3.0.0

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

If you're running python3 than run it like this:

pip3 install --upgrade oauth2client